# Serving html files in nodejs without using fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building one web application, nodejs is my webserver. I want to send response from nodejs for the images,html,css,js,other files.

I want to know which nodejs module is providing to serve my UI files without using fs module which is internally available in nodejs.

Constraint: If i use fs module or express which internally uses fs, if a new file is added it should be generated for the response.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your constraint more clearly? From what I read, you mean you want to serve not only files which exist when the server is started, but also files that are added later. Isn't that exactly what express.static does, look for the file and serve it if available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Express/Connect static middleware:

```js
var app = require('express').createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000);
```

But the best way is configuring nginx or similar frontend server to proxy dynamic requests to node.js and direct return static files.